# ability to change layout of html dynamically by user

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How do I provide user the ability to change the layout of the dashboard dynamically at run time by dragging and moving the components and resizing them. I am using angularjs and bootstrap as of now. How do I proceed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best for you would be to use a library such as :

- [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists)

OR

- [draggable from greensock](https://greensock.com/draggable)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI has a very nifty function for that:

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

If you can use jquery in your project i would go with that, it even includes functions to do what you are asking, with the sortable function.